# How to automatically connect to mirror svn repo when source repo crashed?

Tags: svn

Are there any way/work around to automatically connect to mirror repository if my source repo crashed?

It hasn't happened to me but I want to know what I can do before that happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to handle this.

The repos UUIDs must match on the mirror and master for probably any solution.

The simplest way is to use the 'svn switch' command to point to the mirror site.
However this results in read only access from the mirror until the master is back up.

For auto read/write failover, and assuming you are using svnsync and apache to create the mirror, one way is as follows:

1. Make sure all repos in in mirror site have the UUIDs set to match the master repos UUIDs.
2. Implement a backup DNS alias entry to switch DNS to upon primary failure
3. Have a name based vhost clone of the primary server setup preconfigured on the mirror site
4. Use some svn hook scripting to detect the primary vhost entry through the mirror
5. Come up with your plan to fail back and untangle the mess.